# How to install a new theme in Magento 2.0.2?

Tags: themes, magento-2.0

I have worked in Magento 1.8. Now I have installed Magento 2.0.2 in localhost. I have one theme named Ultimo which I want to apply in Magento 2.0.2. This theme is not from https://magento.com/.

I can't see my theme name here.

[image: Click to see screenshot of theme page]

Then how to select theme from here? What are the steps to apply a theme?